# Log off user using terminal

Tags: linux, rhel, logout, logoff

I am having a situation where I logged in to a RHEL 5.6 system and started VirtualBox. After closing the VirtualBox, I am having a situation where the menu bar which has the option to *shutdown* or *lock screen* or *log off* the system is not present. I believe the reason might be due to network load or something.

I can *shutdown* or *restart* from the terminal, but again they take considerable amount of time.

All I need is to just **Log off** from the system when the menu bar is not present. I need to get the **login** screen like how we have, when we initially boot the system.

Is there any option to just **Log off** the user using the terminal?

**EDIT:**

ps -ax | grep dm output

```
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ
 2352 ?        S<     0:00 [rdma_cm]
 2908 ?        Ss     0:00 rpc.idmapd
 3287 ?        Ss     0:00 sendmail: accepting connections
 3297 ?        Ss     0:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
 3504 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm-binary -nodaemon
 3547 ?        S      0:01 /usr/sbin/gdm-binary -nodaemon
 3549 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-rh-security-token-helper
 5080 tty7     Ss+    7:20 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -audit 0 -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt7
18166 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep dm
```

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you’re having a situation.

Comment: I am using GNOME.

Comment: Should I use kill command and force logout the user? However, I am not sure if that would lead me to the login screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible ways to get logged out:

- You kill the X server with a key combination: Ctrl-Alt-Backspace, if it is enabled,
- You kill the process of the X server from any terminal (you have to be `root`, but you can do this through SSH remotely as well),
- You ask the window or session manager to quit (how that can be achieved usually depends on the environment used),
- You kill the process of the window or session manager from any terminal (you can do this as your own user or as root, and you can do this through SSH remotely as well),
- You can stop & restart the display manager, if the session is run by a display manager (you have to be `root`, but you can do this through SSH remotely as well). The stopping display manager will kill all its sesssions.

How to know the PID of the X server? Usually, there is only a single X server running on the machine. It runs as `root`. The process name is usually something like `X`, or `Xorg`. It usually has an argument specifying the ID of that X server, `:0` is the first display in the system. Sending a SIGTERM is usually the proper way to stop the X server, using SIGKILL will most probably result in an inproperly shut down graphics display.

How to know which process is the window or session manager? It depends on the environment used. Usually, this is the process that initially starts all processes belonging to the X session. It runs with the credentials of your user. `pstree -up` will show the graph of the processes.

How to know which process is the display manager? If the graphical display is started by a script (`xinit`, for example), there is no display manager. If the graphical display is reachable with XDMCP over the network, there is a display manager. The display manager is usually run as a system service, with whatever service running facility the OS is using (rc.d init scripts, systemd, upstart, etc). Older systems used the generic `xdm` as the display manager, newer desktop environments have their own display manager: `gdm3` for GNOME, `kdm` for KDE, `cde-login` for CDE. Stopping & restarting is done by the appropriate OS service command.

Comment: +1 For the particular case of GNOME, you can run `service gdm3 restart` as root. Or possibly `service gdm restart` if you're using an older version of GNOME.

Comment: @Joseph: thanks, I included the display manager solution as well.

Comment: @JosephR., I do not see any of the services named gdm or gdm3.

Comment: @LaszloValko, Thanks for your detailed explanation. I see a process as xfs and another process as xinetd. These are the 2 processes, I am seeing that starts with X.

Comment: @Ramesh How do you log in?

Comment: When we boot the system, we will be presented with the login screen. I am logging in normally like how we login into RHEL systems.

Comment: @Ramesh: try `ps -ax | grep dm`, it'll probably show which display manager is in use.

Comment: @LaszloValko, I have added the output of ps-ax | grep dm command as an edit to my question.

Comment: +1 for ctrl + alt + backspace. But how to check if it is enabled or disabled?

Comment: @Ramesh: Try it. If it works, it was enabled. If nothing happens, it was disabled. Your `ps` output shows an Xorg server with PID 5080 as :0, that's probably your X server on your console. If you kill that one, it'll get restarted with a new login session. Your display manager is probably `gdm-binary`, it is probably started from a system service with a similar name (gdm, or something like that).